# How do you test code that forks using rspec

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec, rspec2

I have the following code

```
  def start_sunspot_server
    unless @server
      pid = fork do
        STDERR.reopen("/dev/null")
        STDOUT.reopen("/dev/null")
        server.run
      end

      at_exit { Process.kill("TERM", pid) }

      wait_until_solr_starts
    end
  end
```

How would I effectively go about testing it using rspec?

I thought something along

```
Kernel.should_receive(:fork)
STDERR.should_receive(:reopen).with("/dev/null")
STDOUT.should_receive(:reopen).with("/dev/null")
server.should_receive(:run)
```

etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm confused by the `@server` instance variable and `server` method in your example, but here is an example that should help you get where you're trying to go:

```
class Runner
  def run
    fork do
      STDERR.reopen("/dev/null")
    end
  end
end

describe "runner" do
  it "#run reopens STDERR at /dev/null" do
    runner = Runner.new

    runner.should_receive(:fork) do |&block|
      STDERR.should_receive(:reopen).with("/dev/null")
      block.call
    end

    runner.run
  end
end
```

The key is that the `fork` message is sent to the `Runner` object itself, even though its implementation is in the `Kernel` module.

HTH,
David

Comment: I couldn't get this to work if I mock the object (using `expect` matcher) but could get it to work if I stub the object (using `allow` matcher). If the stub is never called, the test won't fail, but you will see an error in the output. Suggest making the stub specific by also specifying arguments it should receive.

Answer (score 1):

David's solution didn't work for us. Maybe it's because we're not using RSpec 2?

Here's what did work.

```
def run
  fork do
    blah
  end
end

describe '#run' do
  it 'should create a fork which calls #blah' do
    subject.should_receive(:fork).and_yield do |block_context|
      block_context.should_receive(:blah)
    end

    subject.run_job
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how this would apply when calling a constant, such as STDERR, but this was the only way we were able to accomplish fork testing.

Comment: it worked for me and i ended up using it in another spot too and had no problems, I do believe I was using Rspec2 on both occasions.